# ¿Por qué cuando elimino un registro de un mat table el paginador deja de funcionar?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-paginator

Tengo la siguiente tabla que muestra  registros que hay en la bd, la tabla muestra los registros de 10 en 10 porque tiene configurado asi el paginador.

La tabla tambien permite editar los campos y eliminar los registros, al momento de eliminar un registro lo hace sin problema y en automatico se refresca la tabla y ya no se muestra lo que se eliminó, esto lo hace cuando eliminas cualquiera de los 10 registros que se muestran primero, si elimino el registro 12, 13 o 14 que ya son parte del otro rango del paginador, cuando se refresca se rompe el paginador y muestra todos los registros completos que hay , como puedo hacer para que al momento de eliminar un registro que es de los posteriores del primer rango del paginador no se rompa  y vuleva a mostrar solamente los registros que hay en  ese rango del paginador donde se elimino el registro

Html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="desc>
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DESCRIPCIÓN </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput type="text" [value]="element.desc"
                    (keyup)="changeValueDesc($event.target,element)"
                    [disabled]="!element.editable">
            </mat-form-field>
            <br>
            <span class="error" *ngIf="element.limiteExcedido">El tamaño máximo para este campo
                es
                de 20</span>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="botonTipoActions">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ACCIONES </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <button mat-icon-button color="primary"
                (click)="actualizar(element,tipoProductoModel)"
                matTooltip="Editar registro">
                <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <button mat-icon-button color="warn"
                (click)="eliminar($event.target,element)"
                matTooltip="Eliminar registro">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns">
    </tr>
</table>
<mat-paginator #paginatorTipo="matPaginator" [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="10"
[pageSizeOptions]="[10]" showFirstLastButtons>
</mat-paginator>
```

**`componet.ts`**:

```
tipoProducto: TipoProducto[] = [];     
@ViewChild('paginatorTipo') paginatorTipo!: MatPaginator;         

dataSource: any;
obtenerTipo() {
  this.productService.obtenerTipo().subscribe(response => {
    if (response.data.length == 0) {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        text: 'Sin datos para mostrar'
      })
    } else {
      this.tipoProducto = response.data;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tipoProducto);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginatorTipo;
    }

  });
}

async eliminar(element: any, row: any) {
  const deleteAlert = Swal.fire({
    title: '¿Está seguro de eliminar los valores?',
    showDenyButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Si',
  });
  if ((await deleteAlert).isConfirmed) {
       const index = this.dataSource.data.indexOf(element);
        this.dataSource.data.splice(index);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataSource.data);
       
       this.tipoProductoModel.idTipo = row.idTipo;
        this.productService.eliminarTipo(this.tipoProductoModel).subscribe(response => {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Éxito',
            text: 'Registro borrado correctamente'
          });
        });
  }
}
```